# PC-Lint treating header as library header

Tags: static-analysis, pc-lint

Using PC-Lint, I'm attempting to make a header file be treated as a library header so that I can suppress messages from inside it.  I'm using the library module option `+libm(module.c)` which should treat module.c as a library module and any headers it includes (i.e module.h) as library headers as described in section 6.1 of the PC-Lint manual for v9.00.  Naturally, module.h is also included in my source files which are not library modules.

The problem is that when I lint the code, I still get messages from module.h even though I provided the `+libm(module.c)` option.  I suspect this is because the module.h file is included in my other non-library modules.  But such a situation is a typical use case and so this makes this `+libm` option useless.  I know I could use `+libh(module.h)` or `+libdir(...)` but I want `+libm(module.c)` to work properly for me.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is not presented like that in the manual, but my experience shows that not all header files included by the library module are considered library. They cannot be: What if the module includes your own header files, the header files you want explicitly to be processed?

Use the Lint option `-vf` (caution: large output!) to see how Lint interprets your header files. Library files are designated as such.
The ones missing can be added using the normal `-lib*` option set.

Comment: "They cannot be: What if the module includes your own header files, the header files you want explicitly to be processed?"

It seems to me that the '+libm' option is provided for those who _know_ that a module is a library module.  For example, my code runs on a third-party RTOS for which I have the source code.  I want to use '+libm' on these modules in order to get inter module value tracking but I do not want to see errors from such modules because I don't maintain them.  Thus, I _know_ those modules do not include my header files so I want '+libm' to work like the manual claims it should.

Comment: Did the `-vf` option shed any light? Then write a bug report to support@gimpel.com, and see what they say. BTW, do you have patch 9.0i, the latest one?